# Will Paginate Reverse order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, reverse, will-paginate

I have a collection with say 118 records.

I'm using the following object: `@tweets = @all_tweets.paginate(:page => page.to_i, :per_page => 100)` to paginate my tweets

Page 1 has 100 records, page 2 has 18.

Say I'm ordering my records in DESC order AND I want to reverse the views. How do I get page 1 to display 18 records and page 2 to show 100 (the max).

Comment: So you want to display a limited amount of records on the first page?

Comment: Yes. I want the order reversed. 18 on the first page (last 18 records), 100 on the second. This is an easy DB query, but to do this in will_paginatate is another issue.

Comment: call .reverse after the call to paginate?

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.wenda120.com/categories/24 , is it what you want?

If so, open view_helpers.rb, find to_html method,
my looks like this:

```
def to_html
  links = @options[:page_links] ? windowed_links : []
  # previous/next buttons
  links.unshift page_link_or_span(@collection.previous_page, 'disabled prev_page', @options[:previous_label])
  links.push    page_link_or_span(@collection.next_page,     'disabled next_page', @options[:next_label])
  html = links.join(@options[:separator])
  @options[:container] ? @template.content_tag(:div, html, html_attributes) : html
end
```

I changed it to this:

```
def to_html
  links = @options[:page_links] ? windowed_links.reverse : []
  # previous/next buttons
  links.unshift page_link_or_span(@collection.next_page,     'disabled next_page', @options[:previous_label])
  links.push    page_link_or_span(@collection.previous_page, 'disabled prev_page', @options[:next_label])
  html = links.join(@options[:separator])
  @options[:container] ? @template.content_tag(:div, html, html_attributes) : html
end
```